# Bad results when undistorting points using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm having trouble undistorting points on an image taken with a calibrated camera using the Python bindings for OpenCV. The undistorted points have entirely different coordinates than the original points detected in the image.

Here's the offending call:

```
undistorted = cv2.undistortPoints(image_points,
                                  camera_matrix,
                                  distortion_coefficients)
```

where `image_points` is a numpy array of detected chessboard corners returned by `cv2.findChessboardCorners` and reshaped to match the dimensional requirements of `cv2.undistortPoints`, and `camera_matrix` and `distortion_coefficients` were returned by `cv2.calibrateCamera`.

`camera_matrix` and `distortion_coefficients` seem to me to be okay, and so do `image_points`. Nevertheless, `distorted` seems to have no relationship to `image_points`. Here's a summary of the values:

```
>>> image_points
array([[[ 186.95303345,  163.25502014]],

       [[ 209.54478455,  164.62690735]],

       [[ 232.26443481,  166.10734558]],

       ..., 

       [[ 339.03695679,  385.97784424]],

       [[ 339.20108032,  400.38635254]],

       [[ 339.13067627,  415.30780029]]], dtype=float32)
>>> undistorted
array([[[-0.19536583, -0.07900728]],

       [[-0.16608481, -0.0772614 ]],

       [[-0.13660771, -0.07537176]],

       ..., 

       [[ 0.00228534,  0.21044853]],

       [[ 0.00249786,  0.22910291]],

       [[ 0.00240568,  0.24841554]]], dtype=float32)
>>> camera_matrix
array([[ 767.56947802,    0.        ,  337.27849576],
   [   0.        ,  767.56947802,  224.04766824],
   [   0.        ,    0.        ,    1.        ]])
>>> distortion_coefficients
array([[ 0.06993424, -0.32645465,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.04310827]])
```

I'm working with reference C code and everything matches up until I make that call. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you forgot to specify the *new camera matrix* in your call to `undistortPoints`. If you look at [the documentation of the function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints), it says that the signature is:

```
Python: cv.UndistortPoints(src, dst, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, R=None, P=None) → None
```

where `dst` is the array of points after undistortion and "if `P` is identity or omitted, then it contains normalized point coordinates", meaning before projection in the image using the calibration matrix.

The function should do what you expect if you set `P` to your `cameraMatrix`.

Comment: That did it! I used the (undocumented) signature from ``cv2``: ``cv2.undistortPoints(image_points, camera_matrix, distortion_coefficients, P=camera_matrix)``

Comment: I am a little confused about what undistortPoints is doing exactly, what does the documentation mean by ideal image coordinates?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 ideal image coordinates are the 2D image coordinate which would have been observed if the lens was ideal with zero distortion. For a real non-ideal lens, you have to account for distortion, which adds an offset on the image coordinates. More details on the camera projection model can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Comment: So the undistortPoints gives us back the image coordinates according to zero-lens distortion?