# undistortPoints() cannot handle lens distortions

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I use openCV function projectPoints() to rotate, translate and project a set of 3D points and solvePnp() to find this rotation and translation. This works well when the lens distortion coefficients are all zero but fails otherwise. It takes as little distortion as this to fail completely:

```
 distCoeffs << 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;
```

The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
#define DEG2RAD (3.1415293/180.0)
#define RAD2DEG (1.0/DEG2RAD)

int main() {
    const int npoints = 10; // number of points

    // extrinsic
    const Point3f tvec(10, 20, 30);
    Point3f rvec(3, 5, 7);
    cout << "Finding extrinsic parameters (PnP)" << endl;
    cout<<"Test transformations: ";
    cout<<"Rotation: "<<rvec<<"; translation: "<<tvec<<endl;
    rvec*=DEG2RAD;

    // intrinsic
    Mat_ <double>cameraMatrix(3, 3);
    cameraMatrix << 300., 0., 200., 0, 300., 100., 0., 0., 1.;
    Mat_ <double>distCoeffs(1, 5); //  (k_1, k_2, p_1, p_2[, k_3[, k_4, k_5, k_6]]) of 4, 5, or 8 elements.
    //distCoeffs << 1.2, 0.2, 0., 0., 0.;  // non-zero distortion
    distCoeffs << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0; // zero distortion
    cout<<"distrotion coeff: "<<distCoeffs<<endl;

    cout<<"============= Running PnP..."<<endl;
    vector<Point3f> objPts(npoints);
    vector<Point2f> imagePoints(npoints);
    Mat rvec_est, tvec_est;
    randu(Mat(objPts), 0.0f, 100.0f);

    // project
    projectPoints(Mat(objPts), Mat(rvec), Mat(tvec), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(imagePoints));

    // extrinsic
    solvePnP(objPts, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec_est, tvec_est);
    cout<<"Rotation: "<<rvec_est*RAD2DEG<<endl;
    cout<<"Translation "<<tvec_est<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**When all distortion coefficients are 0 the result is OK:**

Finding extrinsic parameters (PnP)
Test transformations: Rotation: [3, 5, 7]; translation: [10, 20, 30]
distrotion coeff: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
============= Running PnP...
Rotation: [2.999999581709123; 4.999997813985293; 6.999999826089725]
Translation [9.999999792663072; 19.99999648222693; 29.99999699621362]

**However when they aren't zero the result is totally wrong:**

Finding extrinsic parameters (PnP)
Test transformations: Rotation: [3, 5, 7]; translation: [10, 20, 30]
distrotion coeff: [1.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0]
============= Running PnP...
Rotation: [-91.56479629305277; -124.3631985067845; -74.46486950666471]
Translation [-69.72473511009439; -117.7463271636532; -87.27777166027946]

Since people asked, I am adding **intermediate input** - some 3D points and their projections for non-zero distortion coefficients. My camera matrix was 
cameraMatrix << 300., 0., 200., 0, 300., 100., 0., 0., 1.;

3d points [53.0283, 19.9259, 40.1059]; 2D projection [1060.34, 700.59]
3d points [81.4385, 43.7133, 24.879]; 2D projection [6553.88, 5344.22]
3d points [77.3105, 76.2094, 30.7794]; 2D projection [5143.32, 6497.12]
3d points [70.2432, 47.8447, 79.219]; 2D projection [771.497, 611.726]

Another interesting observation: applying undistort when distCoeff are non zero doesn’t really works (but it does produce identical 2D points when distortion coefficients are all 0):

```
cout<<"applying undistort..."<<endl;
vector<Point2f> imagePointsUndistort(npoints);
undistortPoints(Mat(imagePoints), Mat(imagePointsUndistort), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    cout<<"2d original "<<imagePoints[i]<<"; 2d undistort "<<imagePointsUndistort[i]<<endl;
```

applying undistort...
2d original [1060.34, 700.59]; 2d undistort [0, 0]
2d original [6553.88, 5344.22]; 2d undistort [0, 0]
2d original [5143.32, 6497.12]; 2d undistort [0, 0]
2d original [771.497, 611.726]; 2d undistort [0, 0]

The reason why I tried undistort() is because if one undoes the effect of known intrinsic parameters PnP becomes just a minimum direction problem of the form Ax=0. It needs min. 6 points for an approximate linear solution which is probably further improved with LMA (flags=CV_ITERATIVE). Technically there are only 6DOF and thus 3 points required so other methods (flags=CV_P3P, CV_EPNP) take less points. Anyways, regardless of a method or number of points the result is still invalid with non-zero distortion coefficients. The last thing I will try is to put all points on a 3D plane. It still fails:

```
 for (int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
        objPts[i].z=0.0f;
```

Finding extrinsic parameters (PnP)
Test transformations: Rotation: [3, 5, 7]; translation: [10, 20, 30]
distrotion coeff: [1.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0]
============= Running PnP...
Rotation: [-1830.321574903016; 2542.206083947917; 2532.255948350521]
Translation [1407.918216894239; 1391.373407846455; 556.7108606094299]

Comment: Can you check whether the problem comes from `projectPoints` or `solvePnP` or both ?

Comment: it seems that projectPoints returns quite weird coordinates.

Comment: solvePnP with non-zero distortion coefficient is too basic, too fundamental to be wrong. It is used all over openCV algorithms related to camera calibration and 3D reconstruction. There should be an explanation!

Comment: Another crucial point is that if one uses default parameters in undistortPoints() the result will be in normalized camera coordinates (not image coordinates). Read this in function description “P – New camera matrix (3x3) or new projection matrix (3x4). P1 or P2 computed by stereoRectify() can be passed here. If the matrix is empty, the identity new camera matrix is used."

Comment: Yes, for the record, that last point was also addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027419/bad-results-when-undistorting-points-using-opencv-in-python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to make your code work?**

I am able to reproduce the described behavior using the code you provided, however, either one of the two following options solve the problem:

- Replace `const Point3f tvec(10, 20, 30);` by  `const Point3f tvec(10, 20, N);`  where `N` is *much lower* than 0 (e.g. -300) or *much larger* than 100 (e.g. 300).
- Replace your call to `solvePnP` by a call to `solvePnPRansac`.

**Why does each of these changes fix the undesired behavior?**

First, consider what your original code requests from the `solvePnP` function. You are using a rotation of rather small magnitude, hence for simplicity of the explanation, I will assume that the rotation is identity. Then, the camera is positionned at world coordinates X=10, Y=20 and Z=30 and you generate object points randomly with world coordinates (X,Y,Z) uniformly drawn in [0,100]<sup>3</sup>. **Hence, the camera is in the middle of the possible range for the object points**, as illustrated on the following picture:

[image]

This means that object points may be generated very close to the focal plane (i.e. the plane going through the optical center and perpendicularly with respect to the optical axis). The projection in the camera image for such object points is undefined. **However, in practice the non-linear optimization algorithm for `undistortPoints` is unstable even for object points close to the focal plane**. This unstability causes the iterative algorithm for `undistortPoints` to diverge, except when the coefficients are all zero since in that case the initial values remain strictly constant during the estimation.

Hence, the two possible solutions to avoid this behavior are the following:

- Avoid generating object points near the focal plane of the camera, i.e. change the translation vector *or* the range of the coordinates of the object points.
- Eliminate the object points too close to the focal plane of the camera, whose undistorted estimation diverged (outliers), before the PnP estimation for example using `solvePnPRansac`.

---

**Details about why `undistortPoints` fails:**

NB: As we know the 3D world points, I used the following call to obtain the true undistorted coordinates, independently from the result of `undistortPoints`:

```
cv::projectPoints(obj_pts, rvec, tvec, cv::Mat_<double>::eye(3,3), cv::Mat_<double>::zeros(5,1), true_norm_pts);
```

The following function is a simplified version of what `undistortPoints` is doing:

```
void simple_undistort_point(const cv::Mat &img_pt,
                            const cv::Mat_<double> &K,
                            const cv::Mat_<double> &D,
                            cv::Mat &norm_pt)
{
    // Define temporary variables
    double k[8]={D.at<double>(0),
                 D.at<double>(1),
                 D.at<double>(2),
                 D.at<double>(3),
                 D.at<double>(4)},
           fx, fy, ifx, ify, cx, cy;
    fx = K.at<double>(0,0);
    fy = K.at<double>(1,1);
    ifx = 1./fx;
    ify = 1./fy;
    cx = K.at<double>(0,2);
    cy = K.at<double>(1,2);
    // Cancel distortion iteratively
    const int iters = 5;
    double x, y, x0, y0;
    x0=x=(img_pt.at<double>(0)-cx)*ifx;
    y0=y=(img_pt.at<double>(1)-cy)*ify;
    for(int j = 0; j < iters; ++j)
    {
        double r2 = x*x + y*y;
        double icdist = 1/(1 + ((k[4]*r2 + k[1])*r2 + k[0])*r2);
        double deltaX = 2*k[2]*x*y + k[3]*(r2 + 2*x*x);
        double deltaY = k[2]*(r2 + 2*y*y) + 2*k[3]*x*y;
        x = (x0 - deltaX)*icdist;
        y = (y0 - deltaY)*icdist;
    }
    // Store result
    norm_pt.create(1,2,CV_64F);
    norm_pt.at<double>(0) = x;
    norm_pt.at<double>(1) = y;
}
```

If you add code to check how `x` and `y` change with each iteration, you'll see that the iterative optimization diverges due to `r2` being very large at the beginning. Here is a log example:

```
#0:   [2.6383300, 1.7651500]    r2=10.0766000, icdist=0.0299408, deltaX=0, deltaY=0
#1:   [0.0789937, 0.0528501]    r2=0.00903313, icdist=0.9892610, deltaX=0, deltaY=0
#2:   [2.6100000, 1.7462000]    r2=9.86128000, icdist=0.0309765, deltaX=0, deltaY=0
#3:   [0.0817263, 0.0546783]    r2=0.00966890, icdist=0.9885120, deltaX=0, deltaY=0
#4:   [2.6080200, 1.7448800]    r2=9.84637000, icdist=0.0310503, deltaX=0, deltaY=0
end:  [0.0819209, 0.0548085]
true: [0.9327440, 0.6240440]
```

When `r2` is large, `r2*r2*r2` is huge hence `icdist` is very small, hence the next iteration starts with a very small `r2`. When `r2` is very small, `icdist` is close to 1, hence `x` and `y` are respectively set to `x0` and `y0` and we are back with a large `r2`, etc.

So why is `r2` so large in the first place? Because the points may be generated close to the focal plane, in which case they are far from the optical axis (hence a very large `r2`). See the following log example:

```
img_pt#0=[991.4992804037340, 629.5460091483255], r2=10.07660, norm(cv_undist-true)=1.0236800
img_pt#1=[5802.666489402056, 4402.387472311543], r2=554.4490, norm(cv_undist-true)=2.1568300
img_pt#2=[5040.551339386630, 5943.173381042060], r2=639.7070, norm(cv_undist-true)=2.1998700
img_pt#3=[741.9742544382640, 572.9513930063181], r2=5.749100, norm(cv_undist-true)=0.8158670
img_pt#4=[406.9101658356062, 403.0152736214052], r2=1.495890, norm(cv_undist-true)=0.1792810
img_pt#5=[516.2079583447821, 1038.026553216831], r2=10.88760, norm(cv_undist-true)=1.0494500
img_pt#6=[1876.220394606081, 8129.280202695572], r2=747.5450, norm(cv_undist-true)=2.2472900
img_pt#7=[236.9935231831764, 329.3418854620716], r2=0.599625, norm(cv_undist-true)=0.0147487
img_pt#8=[1037.586015858139, 1346.494838992490], r2=25.05890, norm(cv_undist-true)=1.2998400
img_pt#9=[499.9808133105154, 715.6213031242644], r2=5.210870, norm(cv_undist-true)=0.7747020
```

You can see that for most points, `r2` is very large, except for a few (#3, #4 & #7) which are also those associated with the best undistortion accuracy.

This problem is due to the particular undistortion algorithm implemented in OpenCV, which has been chosen for its efficiency. Other non-linear optimization algorithm (e.g. Levenberg-Marquardt) would be more accurate but also much slower, and would definitely be an overkill in most applications.

Comment: I tried randu(Mat(objPts), 20.0f, 100.0f); with the same result: no distortion works, distortion fails. But Point3f tvec(10, 20, 300);  worked!  I guess pin hole camera model requires f<<Z. Still not clear why zero destortion ALWAYS works.

Comment: OK, you were editing. So it was undistortePoints() that was unstable for the points near the focal plane. Sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Try with `solvePnPRansac`, it works too. About the fact that zero distortion works well, I think this behavior comes from `undistortPoints` (called by `solvePnP`) rather than directly from `solvePnP`. Both implement a non-linear optimization, which diverges in unstable cases. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: it magically does. I used to RANSAC being applied before LMA and thus I though there is no way for it to fix divergence.

Comment: undistortPoints does three things: 1. Undo camera matrix; 2. Iterative optimization to undo distortion; 3. Apply camera matrix again. None of these operations includes division by a small number.  So it is still unclear what causes instability.

Comment: @Vlad You wanted details? See my edit :) You're right, the unstability is not due to division by small values, but it is still related to points being too close to the focal plane. I'll try to check in more details why `solvePnPRansac` is working fine.

Comment: So I'm suffering from divergence as well. I chose points close to the principal point, so that r2 was initially 3.8. Still diverged horribly.

Answer (score 3):

Let me go through opencv sources. But first I present "pure" opencv function that works as in the sources (please read below how I got this point) merged with your code to show it works as the library one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
#define DEG2RAD (3.1415293/180.0)
#define RAD2DEG (1.0/DEG2RAD)

Point2f Project(Point3f p, double R[], double t[], double k[], double fx, double fy, double cx, double cy) {
        double X = p.x, Y = p.y, Z = p.z;
        double x = R[0]*X + R[1]*Y + R[2]*Z + t[0];
        double y = R[3]*X + R[4]*Y + R[5]*Z + t[1];
        double z = R[6]*X + R[7]*Y + R[8]*Z + t[2];
        double r2, r4, r6, a1, a2, a3, cdist, icdist2;
        double xd, yd;

        z = z ? 1./z : 1;
        x *= z; y *= z;

        r2 = x*x + y*y;
        r4 = r2*r2;
        r6 = r4*r2;
        a1 = 2*x*y;
        a2 = r2 + 2*x*x;
        a3 = r2 + 2*y*y;
        cdist = 1 + k[0]*r2 + k[1]*r4 + k[4]*r6;
        icdist2 = 1./(1 + k[5]*r2 + k[6]*r4 + k[7]*r6);
        xd = x*cdist*icdist2 + k[2]*a1 + k[3]*a2;
        yd = y*cdist*icdist2 + k[2]*a3 + k[3]*a1;

        double xRet = xd*fx + cx;
        double yRet = yd*fy + cy;

        return Point2f(xRet, yRet);
}

int main() {
    const int npoints = 10; // number of points

    // extrinsic
    const Point3f tvec(10, 20, 30);
    Point3f rvec(3, 5, 7);
    cout << "Finding extrinsic parameters (PnP)" << endl;
    cout<<"Test transformations: ";
    cout<<"Rotation: "<<rvec<<"; translation: "<<tvec<<endl;
    rvec*=DEG2RAD;

    // intrinsic
    Mat_ <double>cameraMatrix(3, 3);
    cameraMatrix << 300., 0., 200., 0, 300., 100., 0., 0., 1.;
    Mat_ <double>distCoeffs(1, 5); //  (k_1, k_2, p_1, p_2[, k_3[, k_4, k_5, k_6]]) of 4, 5, or 8 elements.
    distCoeffs << 1.2, 0.2, 0., 0., 0.;  // non-zero distortion
    //distCoeffs << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0; // zero distortion
    //distCoeffs << 1.8130418031666484e+000, -1.3285019729932657e+001, -1.6921715019797313e-002, -1.3327183367510961e-001, -5.2725832482783389e+001;
    cout<<"distrotion coeff: "<<distCoeffs<<endl;

    cout<<"============= Running PnP..."<<endl;
    vector<Point3f> objPts(npoints);
    vector<Point2f> imagePoints(npoints);
    Mat rvec_est, tvec_est;
    randu(Mat(objPts), 0.0f, 100.0f);

    // project
    projectPoints(Mat(objPts), Mat(rvec), Mat(tvec), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(imagePoints));

    std::cout << objPts << std::endl;
    std::cout << imagePoints << std::endl;

    double R[9];
    Mat matR( 3, 3, CV_64F, R);
    Mat_<double> m(1,3);
    m << (double)rvec.x, (double)rvec.y, (double)rvec.z;

    Rodrigues(m, matR);
    std::cout << matR << std::endl;
    double t[3] = {tvec.x, tvec.y, tvec.z};
    double k[8] = {1.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    double fx = 300, fy = 300, cx = 200, cy = 100;

    for(int i=0;i<objPts.size();i++)
        std::cout << Project(objPts[i], R, t, k, fx, fy, cx, cy) << "; ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // extrinsic
    solvePnP(objPts, imagePoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec_est, tvec_est);
    cout<<"Rotation: "<<rvec_est*RAD2DEG<<endl;
    cout<<"Translation "<<tvec_est<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

R is rotation, t translation, k distortion. Look at the 'r2' computation - it is x*x + y*y, but x,y is the position (scaled by z though) just after applying translation and rotation. And this r stands for (as [wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29#Software_correction) says) for "square distance in image **projected** by ideal pinhole model". We can say projectPoints implementation is OK.

**How I got this result:**

I'm digging up version 2.4.8. If you go to the calibration.cpp in the calib3d module, start with

```
void cv::projectPoints( InputArray _opoints,
                        InputArray _rvec,
                        InputArray _tvec,
                        InputArray _cameraMatrix,
                        InputArray _distCoeffs,
                        OutputArray _ipoints,
                        OutputArray _jacobian,
                        double aspectRatio )
{
    Mat opoints = _opoints.getMat();
    int npoints = opoints.checkVector(3), depth = opoints.depth();
    CV_Assert(npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F));

    CvMat dpdrot, dpdt, dpdf, dpdc, dpddist;
    CvMat *pdpdrot=0, *pdpdt=0, *pdpdf=0, *pdpdc=0, *pdpddist=0;

    _ipoints.create(npoints, 1, CV_MAKETYPE(depth, 2), -1, true);
    CvMat c_imagePoints = _ipoints.getMat();
    CvMat c_objectPoints = opoints;
    Mat cameraMatrix = _cameraMatrix.getMat();

    Mat rvec = _rvec.getMat(), tvec = _tvec.getMat();
    CvMat c_cameraMatrix = cameraMatrix;
    CvMat c_rvec = rvec, c_tvec = tvec;

    double dc0buf[5]={0};
    Mat dc0(5,1,CV_64F,dc0buf);
    Mat distCoeffs = _distCoeffs.getMat();
    if( distCoeffs.empty() )
        distCoeffs = dc0;
    CvMat c_distCoeffs = distCoeffs;
    int ndistCoeffs = distCoeffs.rows + distCoeffs.cols - 1;

    if( _jacobian.needed() )
    {
        // cut out, we dont use this part
    }

    cvProjectPoints2( &c_objectPoints, &c_rvec, &c_tvec, &c_cameraMatrix, &c_distCoeffs,
                      &c_imagePoints, pdpdrot, pdpdt, pdpdf, pdpdc, pdpddist, aspectRatio );
}
```

Nothing special, right? No content manipulation at all. Let's go deeper:

```
CV_IMPL void cvProjectPoints2( const CvMat* objectPoints,
                  const CvMat* r_vec,
                  const CvMat* t_vec,
                  const CvMat* A,
                  const CvMat* distCoeffs,
                  CvMat* imagePoints, CvMat* dpdr,
                  CvMat* dpdt, CvMat* dpdf,
                  CvMat* dpdc, CvMat* dpdk,
                  double aspectRatio )
{
    Ptr<CvMat> matM, _m;
    Ptr<CvMat> _dpdr, _dpdt, _dpdc, _dpdf, _dpdk;

    int i, j, count;
    int calc_derivatives;
    const CvPoint3D64f* M;
    CvPoint2D64f* m;
    double r[3], R[9], dRdr[27], t[3], a[9], k[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, fx, fy, cx, cy;
    CvMat _r, _t, _a = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, a ), _k;
    CvMat matR = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, R ), _dRdr = cvMat( 3, 9, CV_64F, dRdr );


    // some code not important ...


     if( r_vec->rows == 3 && r_vec->cols == 3 )
{
    _r = cvMat( 3, 1, CV_64FC1, r );
    cvRodrigues2( r_vec, &_r );
    cvRodrigues2( &_r, &matR, &_dRdr );
    cvCopy( r_vec, &matR );
}
else
{
    _r = cvMat( r_vec->rows, r_vec->cols, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(r_vec->type)), r );
    cvConvert( r_vec, &_r );
    cvRodrigues2( &_r, &matR, &_dRdr );
}
```

Last part is important, because we use cv::Rodriguez to create an rotation matrix from rotation vector. And later in the function we also create translation matrix, but still no data manipulation. Going further in the ProjectPoints2:

```
    fx = a[0]; fy = a[4];
    cx = a[2]; cy = a[5];

    if( fixedAspectRatio )
        fx = fy*aspectRatio;

    if( distCoeffs )
    {
        if( !CV_IS_MAT(distCoeffs) ||
            (CV_MAT_DEPTH(distCoeffs->type) != CV_64F &&
            CV_MAT_DEPTH(distCoeffs->type) != CV_32F) ||
            (distCoeffs->rows != 1 && distCoeffs->cols != 1) ||
            (distCoeffs->rows*distCoeffs->cols*CV_MAT_CN(distCoeffs->type) != 4 &&
            distCoeffs->rows*distCoeffs->cols*CV_MAT_CN(distCoeffs->type) != 5 &&
            distCoeffs->rows*distCoeffs->cols*CV_MAT_CN(distCoeffs->type) != 8) )
            CV_Error( CV_StsBadArg, cvDistCoeffErr );

        _k = cvMat( distCoeffs->rows, distCoeffs->cols,
                    CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(distCoeffs->type)), k );
        cvConvert( distCoeffs, &_k );
    }
```

Here we set focal lengths from camera matrix and principal point coords. Also we set array k which contains distortion coefs. Now we finished setting up variables. Let's  go to the computations:

```
    double X = M[i].x, Y = M[i].y, Z = M[i].z;
    double x = R[0]*X + R[1]*Y + R[2]*Z + t[0];
    double y = R[3]*X + R[4]*Y + R[5]*Z + t[1];
    double z = R[6]*X + R[7]*Y + R[8]*Z + t[2];
    double r2, r4, r6, a1, a2, a3, cdist, icdist2;
    double xd, yd;

    z = z ? 1./z : 1;
    x *= z; y *= z;

    r2 = x*x + y*y;
    r4 = r2*r2;
    r6 = r4*r2;
    a1 = 2*x*y;
    a2 = r2 + 2*x*x;
    a3 = r2 + 2*y*y;
    cdist = 1 + k[0]*r2 + k[1]*r4 + k[4]*r6;
    icdist2 = 1./(1 + k[5]*r2 + k[6]*r4 + k[7]*r6);
    xd = x*cdist*icdist2 + k[2]*a1 + k[3]*a2;
    yd = y*cdist*icdist2 + k[2]*a3 + k[3]*a1;

    m[i].x = xd*fx + cx;    // here projection
    m[i].y = yd*fy + cy;
```

And we have the function exactly as the one I presented on the top/

Comment: The distortion correction happens after perspective projection but before the application of camera intrinsic so the warping is
relative to the optical axis and not the origin of pixel coordinate system. So you are right and openCV is right. OpenCV help on Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction has all these formulas. I appreciate all your efforts, but what is your point? Are you saying that we can exclude projectPoints() as our suspect and focus on undistort() and solvePnp() instead?

Comment: My point was to check the exact implementation. Because you noticed some weird projectPoints() coordinates and put the into the question opencv implementation, I did some effort to find out. I was not sure about calculation of radius for distortion removal but if you claim that it is okay so I edited the post, and we yes we can exclude projectPoints from suspect because now we know how it works.